# Javascript Monads -- tiered function paths?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

I'm just getting started with Monads and have been learning about Maybe, Either, IO ( aka Task? ).

Is there a Monad that can decide a course of action based on an input? For instance, if the input starts with 'http', execute fn(input). If the input starts with 'shortened', execute fn2(input)? Finally, if the input is 'completed', then fn3(input). Or does this kind of branching violate some functional programming law?

Comment: You just described Either....

Comment: I'm curious about Either as almost all the online sources I've seen limit one of Either's branches to some type of null checking. Can Either be used mimic if .. else ... ?

Comment: if all you're doing is null-checking you should be using `Maybe`. Branching is what `Either` is *for*... here's a decent looking example in typescript https://tech.evojam.com/2016/03/21/practical-intro-to-monads-in-javascript-either/

Comment: Example uses `Either` to replace `try/catch` but the idea is the same.

Comment: "action" and "input" sounds exactly like an IO monad.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks. I looked at tech.evojam and didn't see anything using Either that didn't include "reserving" one of the branches for exceptions, errors, etc or did I miss something?

Comment: I've also updated my original post to include a third branch -- fn3(input) to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Bergi Can you explain how the IO monad can help replicate "if ... else" branching? Thanks.

Comment: @bresson branching is simply done with `if`/`else` or the conditional operator, there's nothing special about it. It works in any monad. But if you want to branch depending on input, and want to perform actions, that's when you choose IO as your monad.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of monadic composition is that you are allowed to do exactly what you're asking -- decide further computation based on previous results.

In concrete terms, let's look at first the (implicit) Javascript monad -- i.e., the non-reified one that you use when writing straightline Javascript code. Here, you can write

```js
var s = document.getElementById("myTextBox").value; // effect: looking at current DOM state
if (s == "foo") 
{
    document.getElementById("output").textContents = "OK." // effect: changing the DOM
} else {
    window.alert("What?"); // effect: popup dialog
}
```

You can see here that the computation, including, importantly, its effect, changes depending on the result of the first action (the result of `getElementById().value`).

In other, reified monads, you can do exactly the same; for example (using Haskell syntax here because I don't know what the popular Javascript monad libraries look like) with `Maybe`:

```hs
parse :: String -> Maybe Command
parse = ...

reply :: String -> Maybe String
reply s = do
    cmd <- parse s -- effect: fails if `s` is not a valid command
    case cmd of 
      Say s' -> Just s' -- effect: succeeds with s'
      _ -> Nothing -- effect: failure
```

The same is happening here: depending on `parse s`'s result, the next effect can be either failure of success.